# Charge over 2 layer dielectric, image method

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, dielectric, method-of-images

If I have a charge $Q$ located over a 2 layer dielectric as represented:
[image: imagemethod2layers]

According to the image method: the charge $Q'1$ will be located at a distance $h_1$ under the first interface and the $Q'2$ will be located at a distance $h_2$ under the first interface.

With:

$$
Q'1 = \frac{\epsilon_0-\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_0+\epsilon_1} = \frac{1-5}{1+5} Q
$$

My problem is determining the value of $Q'2$, is it:
$$
Q'2 = \frac{\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2} = \frac{5-100}{5+100} Q
$$

or

$$
Q'2 = \frac{\epsilon_0-\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_0+\epsilon_2}= \frac{1-100}{1+100} Q
$$

Comment: Two images are not enough, because $Q'_1$ is "reflected" by interface 2 and $Q'_2$ is "reflected" by interface 1. Then these secondary images will themselves produce ternary images, and so on.

Comment: Yes my objective is to write a python script that iterates many times the images of images in order to converge towards the real value. Before I extend to multiple iterations I am trying to get the first iteration right.

Comment: At first glance, option 1 looks correct because $Q'_2$ must vanish when $ε_1=ε_2$. This said, I don't understand why it wouldn't depend on $ε_0$. Maybe option 2 gives the correct result for $ε_1=ε_2$ when all images are taken into account. In any case, once your implementation is ready, it will be easy to try a few simple test cases, then change option if necessary.

Comment: @AnthonyLethuillier this [article](http://www.fisica.unam.mx/personales/rbarrera/pdf/pub/int/8-AJP-46-1172-78.pdf) might help.

Answer (score 2):

From Jackson's *Electrodynamics*: the potential in the $\epsilon_1$ region for a single interface is as if there is an image charge $Q''=\frac{2\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_0}Q$ at the position of $Q$. Therefore the correct $Q'2$ is

$$Q''\frac{\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2}=\frac{2\epsilon_1}{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_0}\frac{\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2}{\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2}Q$$

which seems to have the right behavior in the two limiting cases $\epsilon_0=\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused. Is this expression giving the potential of the $\epsilon_1$ region or the vacuum region? Also, if I'm interested in the potential in the vacuum region, how do I find the position of the next mirror charge (by $Q'2$), which gives the next-order contribution?